# Boot time kernel parameter to ignore module version check

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm testing some custom kernels. But each time I rebuild the bzImage and copy it to `/boot` directory, it refuses to boot and stuck at initramfs.

I recognised the problem as previously built kernel modules are not loading with the new kernel.

```
disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

As they're looking for the exactly same kernel version.

I don't want to rebuild the modules each time.

So is there any way to force the kernel not to check kernel version, like `--force-varmagic` and load them ?

Also is there any way to disable this local version related issue while configuring the kernel ?

#### Updates

1. In my kernel configuration `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` is **y** and `CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD` is also **y** .

Comment: Please do not delete a question and then ask the exact same question again.  This is just annoying and serves no good purpose other than trolling.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, and please let me know exactly how it happened ? I never deleted a question, just edited it after publishing.

Comment: Sorry if my memory played tricks on me.  Weird!